# Do you know about any other approaches to error handling than try/catch and its variations?

Tags: programming-languages, error-handling

I am interesting in knowing some other approaches to error handling in programming languages other than try/catch and its variations.

Does anyone know some interesting cases of such an error handling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there's also good old

```
ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
```

Also, some programming languages (some Lisps and Schemes, maybe Smalltalk) separate *raising an exception* from *escaping* (ie, unwinding the stack). That is, it's possible in some circumstances to handle an exception in the context where it is raised and continue computation---these are called *continuable exceptions*.

Answer (score 3):

In general, it seems that error handling strategies can be divided into three categories:

- Do nothing (`ON ERROR RESUME NEXT`, as Ryan mentioned)
- Indicate error/failure in a return code. This can, in some cases, be an additional output parameter, such as a pointer to an error indicator that gets set in case of error.
- Invoke an alternate control flow. This can be extreme (calling `abort()` to stop the program cold), or take the form of exception handling or something similar.

There are a number of implementations and styles of of alternate control flows. One is POSIX signals, which often result in terminating the program by default. Visual Basic also has an alternate control flow facility in `ON ERROR GOTO`.

Perl combines alternate control flow and return codes by using `die`, which causes the program to terminate, in subinterpreters such that running `die` in an `eval`'d block results in an error code being set in the calling code.

Then, of course, there is traditional exception handling, along with variations such as Common Lisp's restartable/resumable exceptions. Even the signal/`abort()` approach and `ON ERROR GOTO` can be considered primitive exception handling systems. So considering exceptions broadly, most alternative-control-flow error handling systems can be considered to be some form of exception handling.

Actually implementing exceptions opens an interesting set of design spaces. There are several ways the language implementation can do it:

1. Set a flag/abnormal return value and return the caller. What Perl requires you to do explicitly — `die` and check the error variable `$?` — is a manual version of this method. A programming language doing this uses the return-code error handling method to implement exceptions, and may expose them via a try-catch construct; [Vala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_%28programming_language%29) is a good example of this.
2. Unwind the stack (as if functions returned) to the exception handler and run it. This can be done directly, either by VM machinery or by inspecting the stack. It can also be simulated with (2); when used to implement exceptions, these two approaches are pretty much semantically equivalent.
3. Invoke the exception handling code in the dynamic scope of the code throwing the error. This is what Common Lisp does with its `condition-case` construct — the error handler is run without unwinding the stack, and then indicates whether the error is to be handled by retrying or by unwinding.
4. Use [double-barrelled continuation passing](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64044/compilingwithcontinuationscontinued.pdf). In normal continuation-passing style (CPS), rather than returning a value, a function calls another function (called a continuation) which is provided by its caller as one of its arguments with the result to “continue” the computation. In double-barrelled CPS, the caller provides two continuations: one for normal results and one for errors. This can be used to implement semantics equivalent to those of (1) and (2), but is an interesting alternative strategy that may open up the opportunity to build more interesting semantics.

So, in summary: there are three basic approaches: ignore the error, return codes, and various exception-like facilities. But within the space of exception-like facilities, there are a variety of option both for semantics or interface and for implementing those semantics.

Answer (score 2):

There is the good old return-value. [GO](http://golang.org/) actually uses return-values instead of exceptions.
Since C has no exception-mechanism, it uses return-values as well, plus a global variable ([`errno`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h)).

**Edit** My information about GO seems to be out-of-date, as it now has an exception-handling mechanism. Still, return-values can be used to report errors.